# adjust order of one array based on the order of another array that was sorted

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting, indexing

I have two tables, one table for usernames, and one table for scores. I populate those tables with two arrays. The tables need to be in descending order based on the scores. I sort the array with the scores in it, but I am not sure how I can arrange the usernames to stick with their score, they are in a separate array, and a separate table from the scores table. Here is my code:

```
dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:matchesForUser forKeys:tableData];
sortedFirstArray = [dictionary allKeys];
sortedSecondArray = [dictionary objectsForKeys:sortedFirstArray notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
sortedSecondArray = [sortedSecondArray sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
```

I need the `sortedFirstArray` values to stick with their respective `sortedSecondArray` values in terms of their order in each of their arrays.

**UPDATE**

My code attempting to do the sorting:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (!error) {
                entries = [NSMutableArray new];
                for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                    NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
                    [tableData addObject:[object valueForKey:@"username"]];
                    [matchesForUser addObject:[object valueForKey:@"matches"]];

                    NSMutableDictionary* entry = [NSMutableDictionary new];

                    entry[@"username"] = [object valueForKey:@"username"];
                    entry[@"matches"] = [object valueForKey:@"matches"];

                    [entries addObject:entry];

                    //transfer = entries;
                }
                transfer = [entries sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary* a, NSDictionary* b) {
                    NSDate *first  = [a objectForKey:@"matches"];
                    NSDate *second = [b objectForKey:@"matches"];
                    NSLog(first);
                    NSLog(second);
                    return [first compare:second];
                }];
            //dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:matchesForUser forKeys:tableData];
            //sortedFirstArray = [dictionary allKeys];
            //sortedSecondArray = [dictionary objectsForKeys:sortedFirstArray notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
            //sortedSecondArray = [sortedSecondArray sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
            [_tableView reloadData];
            [_tableViewScore reloadData];

        }else{
            NSLog([error description]);
        }

        NSLog(@"***tabledata***");
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[tableData count]]);
        NSLog(@"***matchesdata***");
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[matchesForUser count]]);
    });
}];
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if(tableView.tag == 1) {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:218.0f/255.0f green:247.0f/255.0f blue:220.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:153.0f/255.0f green:211.0f/255.0f blue:212.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    UILabel *contentV = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 230, 44)];
    contentV.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0];
    contentV.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:218.0f/255.0f green:247.0f/255.0f blue:220.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    contentV.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:153.0f/255.0f green:211.0f/255.0f blue:212.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    cell.contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    NSString *username2 = [[transfer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"username"];

    NSLog(@"***username***");
    NSLog(username2);

    contentV.text = username2;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:contentV];

    return cell;
}
else {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:153.0f/255.0f green:211.0f/255.0f blue:212.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:218.0f/255.0f green:247.0f/255.0f blue:220.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *matchAmount = [[transfer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"matches"];
    NSLog(@"***matchamount***");
    NSLog(matchAmount);

    cell.textLabel.text = matchAmount;

    return cell;

}
}
```

Comment: I think you are better off using a _single_ array of dictionaries, each containing a `username` and a `score` (or perhaps a custom class). You can sort them using a custom block that compares the `score` entry of each dictionary, and you can use the same array as data source of both tables (choosing a different entry for each table).

Comment: cool sounds good, can you provide a code example? i think i have a rough idea so no worries if not

Comment: It is pretty straightforward if you know how to use `NSDictionary`'s `-objectForKey:` and `-setObject:forKey:` and `NSArray`'s `-sortedArrayUsingComparator:`.

Comment: great thanks...yup..just needed a refresher

Comment: if you want you can post your comment as an answer, the first one

Comment: An alternative is to generate and sort an array of indices (0 to size-1) according to the scores, then reorder both arrays according to the sorted indices. However, this might need something similar to a C++ lambda function for the compare, and I don't know if this is possible with objective-c. If objective-c supports pointers, pointers  be used instead of indices, in which case the compare function only needs to know the types of the values being compared (after indirection with the pointers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having two separate arrays and going trough the trouble of sorting one of them directly and try to figure out which entries of the other correspond to which in the sorted one, you should instead keep the paired entries of both arrays together in one entity (dictionary or instance of a custom class), and group those in your (single) array:

The actual property names etc. will vary for your code, but the general idea is like this:

```
self.entries = [NSMutableArray new];

for (int i=0; i < userNameArray.count; i++){

    NSMutableDictionary* entry = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    entry["userName"] = [userNameArray objectAtIndex: i];
    entry["score"   ] = [scoreArray objectAtIndex: i]; 
    // ^ TODO: Make sure scoreArray has at least as many elements 
    // as userNameArray!

    [self.entries addObject: entry];
}

self.entries = [self.entries sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary* a, NSDictionary* b) {
    NSDate *first  = [a objectForKey:"score"];
    NSDate *second = [b objectForKey:"score"];
    return [first compare:second];
}];

// (...)

UITableViewCell* tableView:(UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath}) indexPath
{
    NSDictionary* entry = [self.entries objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    if (tableView == self.userNameTableView) {
         // (dequeue user cell...)

         cell.titleLabel.text = [entry objectForKey: "userName"];
         return cell
     }
     else{
         // (dequeue score cell...)

         cell.titleLabel.text = [entry objectForKey: "score"];
         return cell
     }
}
```

Comment: for `self.entries = [self.entries sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary* a, NSDictionary* b) {
    NSDate *first  = [a objectForKey:"score"];
    NSDate *second = [b objectForKey:"score"];
    return [first compare:second];
}];` what are a and b? i see they are paramaters...but then you use them in that block. i created a mutable array of dictionaries like you said just not sure what is going on with the compare...and the NSDate too.

Comment: my code is organizing the scores (i call them matches in my code) 10, 3, 4 instead of 10, 4, 3...im posting what i did

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to NicolasMiari for helping me figure most of this out. Something weird was happening with the way the comparison was being made - and it was producing an unsorted result. This is how I sorted:

```
NSSortDescriptor * descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"matches" ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
NSArray *entrieshold = [entries sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
transfer = [entrieshold copy];
```

It seemed like the most important thing for me was `selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)`. My use of `copy` also may be important...but I don't think so.